# Dimension Discrepancy: Converting Raw Data to Numpy N-Dimensional Array for Classification in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, classification

I have a pretty straightforward question. I'm working on a script to perform multi-label classification with the Scikit-Learn library. My question concerns converting my raw data (which is in JSON format) to NumPy arrays for use with Scikit-Learn's logistic regression classifier. I know from working with the data in Pandas that the dimensions of the data should be 3369 x 76 (3369 instances, and 76 features). But, when I load my JSON data in with my script, and convert it to a NumPy array and call `data.shape` the dimensions are `(3369, 1077)`, so 3369 instances with 1077 features. Perhaps this is something I don't understand about how NumPy works, but if I'm doing something incorrectly and I'm inadvertently generating all of these extra features, I'm worried that any classifiers I attempt to build won't even have a chance at decent performance due to noise introduced by extra features.

So, my questions are two: (1) am I loading in/converting the data correctly for use with Scikit-Learn's classifiers, and (2) if I am converting the data correctly (as far as anyone can tell) what is the reason for the discrepancy in dimensions between the original data and the data after it is converted to NumPy arrays? Thanks in advance for reading. Code below:

**EDIT:** I've pared down the code a bit to just focus on the areas where I'm converting the original data to a NumPy array.

```
import os, json
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, metrics
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split, KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
```

I read in the original data like so:

```
with open('all_labels.json', 'rb') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
```

So now we have a variable `data` which is a list of Python dictionaries, one dictionary per instance in the dataset.

```
# Extract labels from data and assign to separate variable
labels = [i['label'] for i in data]

# Convert labels to numpy format for sklearn to use
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4'])
labels = le.transform(labels)

# Remove target labels from data instances
for i in data:
    del i['label']
```

Here is where I may be going wrong. I'm using Scikit-Learn's `DictVectorizer` to try to convert a Python list of dictionaries (where each dictionary represents an instance of the dataset and each key within a dictionary is a feature for the classifier) to a NumPy array.

```
# THIS IS WHERE I THINK MY MISUNDERSTANDING LIES
# Initialize vectorizer object to convert data instances to 
# numpy format for sklearn
vec = DictVectorizer()
data = vec.fit_transform(data).toarray()
data.shape # (3369, 1077)
```

Hopefully this direct people to the specific problem I'm having in the script.

Comment: That's quite a wall of code. Can you try and cut it down to just where the extra dimensions show up, then test it using a dummy dataset? You may find the problem yourself while doing so, and even if you don't it will be easier for people to help if they have a running example to work with.

Comment: Fair point, Jamie. I'll edit the code down and try your suggestion in a bit.

Comment: It looks like the `DictVectorizer` you are using is one-hot encoding your data. This means that it has identified your data as categorical (are they, e.g. a finite number of string labels?) and provides one column for each unique label, placing a 1 if it is present in a given sample and a 0 otherwise. This is a pretty standard way of encoding categorical data for machine learning. If it seems not right, check out `vec.vocabulary_` and see if it makes sense.

Comment: @eickenberg this is helpful. So, it looks like it is treating some of my features as categorical, however I have a mix of categorical and continuous features within the dataset. My hunch is I'll have to convert the categorical data somehow, but not sure how to proceed with that. Researching now.

Comment: my hunch was that it goes by data type, but I guess only a look into the code can answer that.

Comment: yeah it does one hot encoding if the dictionary value is any string type, see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py#L161). Are you sure your numerical features are not encoded as strings also? If so, try converting them to floats before applying the `DictVectorizer`

Comment: Here's what I'm finding. The one-hot encoding is almost certainly what's contributing to the bloated number of features in my vectorized dataset. Since the values of some of my attributes in the original dataset are strings, each unique string in each attribute is changed to another attribute with something like a boolean (1,0) value for presence or absence in each instance within the dataset. So, the NumPy encoding is behaving as it should, I just wasn't understanding what was happening under the hood. Thanks to all who contributed.